# overload resolution with template substitution and type conversion

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Why are these overloads ambiguous? The first one requires just one type conversion while the second requires template substitution + type conversion, why isn't the first one picked?

```cpp
void foo(int, float){ //  1
    std::cout << "1\n";
}
template <typename T>
void foo(T, int){} // 2

// Type your code here, or load an example.
int main() {
    foo(3.4f, 4.5f); // ambiguous
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rank of conversions for different overloads is compared only between argument/parameter pairs at the same position. No aggregation or comparison between conversion sequences at different positions is done.

Also, template argument deduction does not affect conversion ranks in any way. Only if the conversion sequences are equally good for all arguments are the template properties considered.

`T` is deduced to `float`.

And then the first argument has a better rank for the conversion sequence in the second overload (identity conversion sequence with rank "Exact" vs. floating-integral conversion with rank "Conversion").

So, because of that alone, either the second overload is chosen or the overload resolution is ambiguous, because the conversion sequence for the first argument is worse in the first overload.

Then it turns out that the conversion rank of the second parameter is worse in the second overload, and so overload resolution is ambiguous. For one overload to be better it must not have a worse conversion sequence in any argument/parameter pair.

Answer (score 3):

The basic rule for overload resolution is that for one overload to be selected, the conversion sequence for **every** parameter must be **at least as good as** the conversion sequence for that parameter with the other overload, and there must be at least one parameter for which the conversion sequence is better than it is for the other overload.

In this case, each available overload has one parameter for which there's a conversion from `float` to `int` where the other would be accepting the `float` without a conversion (officially called an identity conversion, not that it matters for now). `float` -> `int` is worse than `float` -> `float`, so in each case, there's one parameter with a worse conversion sequence than for the other overload, so neither one is selected as better than the other.